# QISKit Connection

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, error-correction

I ve beeen trying to use the qiskit package from spyder IDE inisde anaconda (Python version 3.7) but when i try to acces my account I get the following error:

```
 runfile('H:/Python Projects/QComputing/account_save.py', wdir='H:/Python Projects/QComputing')
[{'token': 'MYTOKEN', 'url': 'https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/api'}]

runfile('H:/Python Projects/QComputing/account_save.py', wdir='H:/Python Projects/QComputing')
[{'token': 'MYTOKEN', 'url': 'https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/api'}]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-c4b9a517fa2c>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('H:/Python Projects/QComputing/account_save.py', wdir='H:/Python Projects/QComputing')

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\QComputing\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\QComputing\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "H:/Python Projects/QComputing/account_save.py", line 14, in <module>
    qsk.IBMQ.load_accounts()

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\QComputing\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\ibmq\ibmqprovider.py", line 199, in load_accounts
    self._append_account(credentials)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\QComputing\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\ibmq\ibmqprovider.py", line 279, in _append_account
    single_provider = IBMQSingleProvider(credentials, self)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\QComputing\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\ibmq\ibmqsingleprovider.py", line 52, in __init__
    self._api = self._authenticate(self.credentials)

  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\QComputing\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\ibmq\ibmqsingleprovider.py", line 103, in _authenticate
    .format(ex)) from root_exception

ConnectionError: Couldn't connect to IBMQ server: error during login: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I run only the following commands:

```
import qiskit as qsk
print(qsk.IBMQ.stored_accounts())
qsk.IBMQ.load_accounts()
```

and i have already created an account(with account save command). I have tried closing the antivirus software. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What version of qiskit are you running? Specifically qiskit-ibmq-provider? You can see all of your qiskit verisons by importing qiskit: `import qiskit` and then running `qiskit.__qiskit_version__`

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this code:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ

IBMQ.save_account('your_api_token')
```

And for access:

```
IBMQ.load_account()# without the 's'
```

Hope this helps.